# pricing crypto quanto swap and perpetual

Tags: futures, currency, cryptocurrency, quanto

https://www.bitmex.com/app/contract/ETHUSD
https://www.bitmex.com/app/contract/ETHUSDM21

How do you apply stochastic quanto pricing formulas to quanto crypto futures and perpetuals? I can see couple limitations:

- There is no risk free rate in crypto currencies (BTC) to do domestic
  currency discounting in BTC
- with so many price jumps they are not following lognormal price dynamics

Comment: About 8 years ago, when XBT 1 was worth about USD 1, I was pricing some structured trades involving XBT (did not get executed, unfortunately). I assumed that someone was willing to lend/borrow XBT for up to 5 years at some fixed rate. of course the rate we assumed was much less than what it turned out to be.

Comment: sorry, I meant "when XBT 1 was worth about USD 100" (i.e. 2013-ish).

Comment: @DimitriVulis you priced them for a client?

Comment: I priced them for a sell-side desk that receved a client enquiry. Basically, the client was looking into variants of XBT-denominated CDS: pay upfront, receive XBT in some years only if some credit events happen (or conversely doesn't happen).

Comment: what is your discounting in XBT measure